# Find constant C, Accept-Reject Algorithm

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Suppose I have density
$$f(x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}.$$

There exists a constant $c > 1$ such that $\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} \le c$.

I choose $g(t) = e^{-x} $ since it has heavier tails than $f(t)$. I get to $\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t(1+\frac{1}{2}t)}, \text{ with }\, t\ge 0$ and then get stuck on how to determine what this constant will be.

From here, how do I find $c$?

Comment: Probably want to specify this is for $ t \geq 0$.

Comment: Start by finding where the ratio has a maximum and see what that maximum value is.

Comment: Also, double-check your work. At the moment there’s a sign error in the exponential term.

Comment: $-\frac{t^2}{2}+t$ is maximised when $t=1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t(1+\frac{1}{2}t)}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot e^{1/2}\cdot e^{-\frac{(t+1)^2}{2}}\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot e^{1/2} \quad $, when $t$ is allowed to have any value, corresponds to the following figure (maximum occurs at $t=-1$).

[image]

**When** $t \geq 0$: the function $e^{-\frac{(t+1)^2}{2}}$ is decreasing as $t$ increases and hence attains maximum value when $t=0$. i.e., $\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, corresponds to the following figure (maximum occurs at $t=0$)

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I am following, where did you get ((1+t)^2)/2 from?

Comment: I’m sorry, I am missing where +1 is coming from here

Comment: $−t(1+\frac{1}{2}t)=−\frac{1}{2}(t^2+2t)=−\frac{1}{2}(t^2+2t+1)+\frac{1}{2}=−(t+1)^2+\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thank you for clearly mapping this out, this makes sense now